# Jbehave : Story File Execution with Meta Filter on Eclipse (Local)

Tags: eclipse, selenium, jbehave

I have a smoke suite having xx test Cases. I have applied the Meta filter on only smoke level test cases. But when I tried with *.story as argument for eclipse, its hangup the execution while excluding the test cases as per the Meta Filter.

ENVIRONMENT: variable:- STORY_META_FILTER
Value:-  +smoke

Story file Structure:

```
Scenario : test_xyz

Meta : @smoke

Given TEST1
When TEST2
Then TEST3
```

Can Anyone know the correct way to implement it in Eclipse? What will be the argument for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set environment Variable with `Meta_Filter` and having value as `+smoke`

and run the story file with **`*.story`**